# Retrieving user array from Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase DB with array data that I would like to retrieve from a user. Specifically, `addnote`, with info `Du the dishes`. For reference, I have included an image of my database.

[image]

My DB in JSON Format. I have tried cutting down on some of the excess on account of me horsing around:

```
{
  "items" : {
    "-KSm_hb4Rw4rudtjxq6x" : {
      "addnote" : "Red"
    },
    "-KSmc45MdhuXIkNkoiN-" : {
      "addnote" : "Red"
    },
    "-KSmc8ZsUDGb23MapKl9" : {
      "addnote" : "Red"
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "PYuSE6zyAENdKREZGTHm5VH1DXn1" : {
      "addnote" : {
        "-KSnELpl7-dkmjlyGl2x" : "Du the dishes",
        "-KSnFBaM4VXOyFTjWtaE" : "Du the dishes",
        "-KSnFDlC9hND-M3C2pWE" : "Du the dishes"
      },
      "useremail" : "majohjn@asd.com",
      "username" : "asdasd"
    },
    "ag1ZF6Z4cEZ5AsvusiSD9Z1WyUn2" : {
      "useremail" : "bacon@bacon.com",
      "username" : "jaconb"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to know how to re-arrange the code on my constructor so that it receives my `addnote` items with respect to its user.

```
constructor(af: AngularFire){
this.addsnotes = af.database.list('users/' + addnote);//should fetch my notes.
}  


addSubmit(){
    var self = this;
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var getUserInfo = firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid); 
    if (user){getUserInfo.child('addnote').push("Du the dishes");}  
}
```

Below is the HTML I would like to print this out to:

```
<li *ngFor="let addsnote of addsnotes | async">{{ addnote }}</li>
```

**EDIT:** Fixed my code. Changed the `li` to call `{{addnote}}` so that now the call works. However, I get an [object Object] on my array.

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
private username: string;
private addsnotes: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

constructor(af: AngularFire){
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
this.addsnotes = af.database.list('users/'+user.uid+'/addnote');
}  
ngOnInit(){
var self = this;
}

addSubmit(){
    var self = this;
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var getUserInfo = firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid); 
    if (user){
        getUserInfo.child('addnote').push("Du the dishes");
        }   

}

}
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
this.addsnotes = af.database.list('users/'+user.uid+'/addnote');
```

Comment: thanks! only one lingering issue (hopefully). when called inside the constructor, I get a `uid` of null error. What should I be setting `uid` to? Currently I get a bunch of dots (indicating that the li element is indeed present). However, I get no text, and I get a uid error.

Comment: I added my full ts code to the question. The HTML remains unchanged.

Comment: I altered the HTML from `{{addsnote?addnote}}` to `{{addnote}}` and now my list shows `[object Object]`